# Passing parameters to login_redirect_url

Tags: python, django

I'd like my login page to redirect a user to an instance of a page. Such an instance will be denoted as follows:

> > www.example.com/adminpage/username

This is what I have in my **settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'leicunnadmin'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

In the **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    path('leicunnadmin/<str:user>', views.leicunnAdmin, name='leicunnadmin'),
]
```

The following is the code from the **views.py** script. My aim here was to check that the **user** is **authenticated**, get their **username** and append that to the URL. (The code)

```
@login_required
def leicunnAdmin(request, user):
    username = None
    User = get_user_model()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
        get_logged_user = User.objects.get(username=user)
        print('get_logged_user: '+username)
        return render(request, 'leicunnadmin.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login')
```

Instead what I get when I log in is **www.example.com/adminpage**. When I type in the logged in username (www.example.com/adminpage/**manuallytypedusername**), it then redirects to the right page. Is there no way to automate this?

Comment: I also happen to have same query. Did you find the answer?

Comment: Not yet, opted for an alternative